# How to solve MTOUCH (MT2002) error in Xamarin.iOS with System.Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin iOS project that has been working fine on the simulator and also while deploying directly to my iPad. I recently uploaded it to the app store and everything went well except the size. It was 142mb and it needs to be <=100mb so I thought using Linker would be a good idea to bring the size down but I keep getting this error:

```
Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator 
System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod::GetILGenerator()" reference 
from "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" (MT2002)
```

Comment: Have a look at this page https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#System.Reflection.Emit

Comment: Thanks Jack I'm new to both Xamarin and iOS and I really don't understand this. Can you please help me understand

Comment: @Alfy Are you actually using `System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator`? If it was added by accident remove the package and/or reference, if you (or a 3rd-party library) is dependent upon runtime IL/JITing you will need to redesign your iOS app (Note: runtime IL/JIT is allowed on Android)

Comment: @SushiHangover I am not using it in any of my code and I can't seem to find the package/reference for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after taking a lot of time in editing and refactoring my code. I had to create a new solution, literally copy and paste over all the code and it worked!!! I think it was something to do with manually tinkering with the .csproj files.